# Three panes and one main layout with fixed and scrollbar

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Trying to make:

- `three panes` (all starting from `left` of the screen), each `20%` width of screen width
- `one main section` with width always `100%` of screen width
- so when the `panes` are open, either one or two or all three, the `main section` goes `off-canvas` (pushed to the right)

[image]

What I tried and where I got stuck:

```
<body className="flex h-screen overflow-x-scroll">
    <div className="overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll w-[20%]">Pane-one</div>
    <div className="overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll w-[20%]">Pane-two</div>
    <div className="overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll w-[20%]">Pane-three</div>
    <div className="w-full">
        <main>Main content -Main content -Main content -Main content</main>
    </div>
</body>
```

- If I add `fixed` to each `pane`, then all panes overlap. But my `main section` does what I want. Each of the `three panes` need `position:fixed` when I scroll down on the `main section`.
- A horizontal scrollbar I have for the entire body, but the `main section` shrinks to fit the screen width, and I need it to go `off-canvas` with always 100% width of the screen width.

Comment: use a grid to accomplish your design layout

Comment: @fatpenguin- I made my post more clear with better description and with an image. Why `grid` and not flexbox?

Comment: Okay, now I see exactly what you want, do you think that's a good idea? Imagine someone reading some material on your website. He clicks open a menu, and whatever he has been reading flies off to the side of the screen...

Comment: @fatpenguin - its google map that is getting pushed

Comment: So 60% of your screen is taken up by goole map? Since your design has 3 collapsible panes that takes up a max of 60%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the unit `vw` for screen width and use `grid grid-cols-[20vw_20vw_20vw_100vw]` instead of `flex`.

Here is a Tailwind playground, see if fits your needs.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/e0ifASAwhQ

Comment: thanks, and second part of the question was how to make `pane-1` and `pane-2` and `pane-3` (all individually) position:fixed when you vertically scroll the `main` section? Here... https://play.tailwindcss.com/U2PFVPZ8rr

Comment: Not sure it this it what you want. https://play.tailwindcss.com/TTgwQeFfdT

Comment: unfortunately not, the panes 1,2,3, do not have a verticall scrollbar, cannot scroll down.